# Python solving multiple nonlinear equations where one equation has different forms depending on the range of one of the variables

Tags: python

I need to find the values of multiple variables that satisfy multiple non-linear equations. One of these equations should have a value of zero over a specific range and a function otherwise. Is there a possible way to use fsolve within scipy to solve this?

Example:
Q,T,K,W,H,L are known parameters (constants)
I am solving for a,b,c and d. 
my functions are

- First :

  `c = math.pi * T * (b - a) / math.log((b - 3.3)/ 0.059)`

  - Second:

  `c = K / (2.0 * W) * (b ** 2 - H ** 2)`

  - Third:

  `d= 0 , when (a - 102.5) <=0`

  `d = 0.02 * (31.26 - 0.74 * ((a-102.5) * 100.0)) * (((a-102.5)*100.0)**1.48) , when (a - 102.5) > 0`

  - Fourth:

  `Q + c * L + d * 3.6 = 0`

I guess a rephrase of my question could be : ( is it possible to represent the third function in fsolve)?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/), Python's symbolic math library, can help?
There is a function [`Piecewise`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#sympy-functions-elementary-piecewise) to represent conditional functions.
Apart from a symbolic solver (`solve`), sympy also has a numeric solver, [`nsolve`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html).

The code could then look like:

```py
from sympy import pi, log, Eq, Piecewise, nsolve
from sympy.abc import Q, T, K, W, H, L, a, b, c, d

eq1 = Eq(c, pi * T * (b - a) / log((b - 3.3) / 0.059))
eq2 = Eq(c, K / (2 * W) * (b ** 2 - H ** 2))
eq3 = Eq(d, Piecewise((0, a - 102.5 < 0),
                      (0.02 * (31.26 - 0.74 * ((a - 102.5) * 100.0)) * (((a - 102.5) * 100.0) ** 1.48), True)))
eq4 = Eq(Q + c * L + d * 3.6, 0)

all_eq = [e.subs({Q: 20, T: 10, K: 1, W: 1, H: 1, L: 1}) # fill in specific values for the parameters
          for e in (eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4)]

sol = nsolve(all_eq, (a, b, c, d),  # numerically solve for a,b,c,d
                     (1, 10, 1, 1)) # give initial values for a,b,c,d (here b should be larger than 3.3)
```

Comment: Was this answer helpful?